# Angular4 / RxJS Observables Getting Child Records

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm building a frontend for a blog. I need to be able to get an array of posts from the API and then, for each of those, make a new call to the API for the featured image objects and attach those to their parent Post objects. And finally return the array of complete Post objects. It has been difficult to track down the best way to go about this with Observables.

What I have so far:

```
export class PostService {
private apiAddress: string = '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';
private logger: Logger;

constructor (private httpService: HttpService, private loggerService: LoggerService) {
    this.logger = loggerService.newLogger('PostService');
}

getPosts(category: Category, page: number = 1, pageSize: number = 10): Observable<Post[]> {
    this.logger.log(`getPosts(id:${category.id}, ${page}, ${pageSize}) returned`);
    return this.httpService.get(`${this.apiAddress}?categories=${category.id}&page=${page}&per_page=${pageSize}&orderby=date&order=desc`).map<Response, Post[]>((res) => {
        let posts:Post[] = [];

        let body = res.json();
        for (var i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
            posts.push(new Post(body[i]));
        }

        this.logger.log(`getPosts(id:${category.id}, ${page}, ${pageSize}) returned ${posts.length} posts`);
        return posts;
    });
}
}
```

An idea of what I'd LIKE to do:

```
export class PostService {
private apiAddress: string = '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';
private logger: Logger;

constructor (private httpService: HttpService, private loggerService: LoggerService) {
    this.logger = loggerService.newLogger('PostService');
}

getPosts(category: Category, page: number = 1, pageSize: number = 10): Observable<Post[]> {
    this.logger.log(`getPosts(id:${category.id}, ${page}, ${pageSize}) returned`);
    return this.httpService.get(`${this.apiAddress}?categories=${category.id}&page=${page}&per_page=${pageSize}&orderby=date&order=desc`).map<Response, Post[]>((res) => {
        let posts:Post[] = [];

        let body = res.json();
        for (var i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
            posts.push(new Post(body[i]));
        }

        this.logger.log(`getPosts(id:${category.id}, ${page}, ${pageSize}) returned ${posts.length} posts`);
        return posts;
    }).forEach((post, done) => {
        this.httpService.get(`/wp-json/wp/v2/media/${post.featured_media}`).map<Request, Media>((res) => {
            let body = res.json();
            post.featured_image = new Media(body);
            done(post);
        });
    });
}
}
```

I may be thinking of Observables completely the wrong way. I'd appreciate any feedback. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the response of first request to stream and then perform another request.

> Never mix rx programming with for loop , its a bad practice

Your code should look like this :

```
url = `${this.apiAddress}?categories=${category.id}
        &page=${page}&per_page=${pageSize}
        &orderby=date&order=desc`
mediaUrl = `/wp-json/wp/v2/media/${post.featured_media}`;

getPosts(category: Category, 
         page: number = 1, 
         pageSize: number = 10): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.httpService.get(url)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .flatMap(posts => Observable.from(posts))
      .map(post => new Post(post))
      .flatMap(post=> 
         this.httpService.get(mediaUrl)
             .map(res=>res.json())
             .map(image=> Object.assign(post, {
                    featured_image: new Media(body) 
                   }) 
              )
      ).toArray();

}
```

Before I explain what I did, let me tell you how to debug this. 
if you are not sure what is happening between two operators , use `do` .

```
...
.map(res => res.json())
.do(data=> console.log(data))
.flatMap(
...
```

`do` will just print the data in console and proceed with the execution.
What I am doing here step by step :

```
.map(res => res.json())
```

converted stream which contains the response to stream of res.json data

```
.flatMap(posts => Observable.from(posts))
```

Each stream contains an array, we dont want that. We want to take each item one by one. So converting `stream<data[]>` to `stream<data>`

```
.map(post => new Post(post))
```

Converting each raw object to post object

```
.flatMap(post=>
```

Now for each obj, we want to do another http call . So, using flatMap, I am doing a http call, get the response and modify the response and add the object back to stream.

```
.map(image=> Object.assign(post, {
                featured_image: new Media(body) 
               }) 
          )
```

Taking the media response and returning post object with a new param `featured_image` added to post.

Comment: This was perfect and makes total sense. Exactly the kind of elegant solution I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can see you arte making two http request one for getting posts and another to get feature media,

In this case instead of issuing two http request why  dont you adjust your backend to retuen data like

```
postdata : [
  {postid:1, postname:"something else, 
      children:[
            {childid :1, childname:first child item},
            {childid :2, childname:second child item}
          ]
    }  //this is a post with children items in it

  {postid :2, postname: "numbsertwo",
         children:[
                   ...return like in the above
                 ]

      }
```

I hope you get my idea then youcan easily loop through them via

```
 return this.httpService.get(`$urltoget`).map<Response, Post[]>((res) => {
    let posts:Post[] = [];

    let body = res.json();
    for (var i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
        posts.push(new Post(body[i]));

       //here loop through the children

    }

    return posts;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along these lines

```
getPosts(category: Category, page: number = 1, pageSize: number = 10) {
    this.logger.log(`getPosts(id:${category.id}, ${page}, ${pageSize}) returned`);
    return this.httpService.get(`${this.apiAddress}?categories=${category.id}&page=${page}&per_page=${pageSize}&orderby=date&order=desc`).map((res) => {
        let posts:Post[] = [];

        let body = res.json();
        for (var i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
            posts.push(new Post(body[i]));
        }

        this.logger.log(`getPosts(id:${category.id}, ${page}, ${pageSize}) returned ${posts.length} posts`);
        return posts;
    }).
    switchMap(posts => {
        const requestsForImage = new Array<Observable>();
        forEach(post => {
            requestsForImage.push(this.httpService.get(`/wp-json/wp/v2/media/${post.featured_media}`).map(res => {
                   let body = res.json();
                   post.featured_image = new Media(body);
                }
             ));
        })
        return Observable.combineLatest(requestsForImage).map(() => posts);
    })
}
```

The basic idea is to send a first http request to retrive the posts, then create an Array of other http requests, one per each Post, to retrieve the images of each Post. Since an http request is an Observable, you have created an Array of Observables.

You can combine an Array of Observables into a new Observable which emits when all the Observables of the Array have emitted. This is achieved via the combineLatest operator.

The last map operator is used to make sure that what the subscriber receives is the array of Posts created as a result of the first http call.